# Progress Dialog in Android doesn't Show?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Okay.. I am doing something similar to the below:

```
private void onCreate() {
    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait..", "Doing stuff..", true);
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        //do some serious stuff...
        dialog.dismiss();           
    }
};
t.start(); 
t.join();
stepTwo();

}
```

However, what I am finding is that my progress dialog never even shows up. My App stalls for a moment so I know it is chugging along inside of thread t, but why doesnt my dialog appear?

IF I remove the line:

```
t.join();
```

Then what I find happens is that the progress dialog does show up, but my app starts stepTwo(); before what happens in the thread is complete..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use an handler

```
public class MyActivity {

private Handler handler;

private void onCreate() {

   handler = new Handler() {

      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
         pd.dismiss();
         stepTwo();
      }
   };

   final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait..", "Doing stuff..", true);
   Thread t = new MyThread() {
   t.start():

}

private class MyThread extends Thread() {
   public void run() {
      //do some serious stuff...
      handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);       
   }
}   

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Sebi - I have never worked with Handlers before.. I attempted the implementation as you have it, but received some errors (specifically around
private class MyThread extends Thread()) So I was unable to get this to work.. Is there no easier solution in my initial code to ensure PD appears?

Comment: Thread t = new MyThread() {
   t.start():
   };

this is wrong. the correct is 

Thread t = new MyThread();
t.start();

Answer (score 2):

Your join() line blocks the UI thread that runs the ProgressDialog. You are therefore blocking layouts, drawings, etc.

Comment: I see. So a handler is the only way around this?